# Adding Space in nested href tags

Tags: html, css, jsp

I want to add space in the href tag as

```
<li>
 <a href="#title">Title</a>
 <ul>
   <li><href="#name of emp">Name</a>
   <li><href="#age of emp">age</a>
 </ul>
</li>
```

and access the page as #title#name of emp is it possible but the output is not coming for me but the individual links works....

Comment: Can you post your HTML or example ?

Comment: This is very unclear. Can you clarify what you are trying to do and what doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **CSS** to add this space, which can be simulated using `padding` in the `<li>` elements or `margin` in the `<a>` link itself.

**This is a DEMO:**

```css
li ul li {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color:red;
  max-width:40px;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a href="#title">Title</a>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#name of emp">Name</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#age of emp">age</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

**Note:**

You have to use closing tags for `<li>` elements, and there's no `href` tag it should be `<a href="#age of emp">age</a>`.